# preg_match decimals not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I seem to be having a problem with a preg_match code, I am trying to get the decimal number from a string which should be something like '3.25' but instead I get '1'

```
preg_match('/[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?/', 'Â£3.25', $matches);
echo 'match: '.$matches[0];
```

prints "1"

Comment: What does `print_r($matches);` output?

Comment: @mk_89, that is odd. I get `3.25`. You sure there aren't any other factors affecting it?

Comment: What version of php are you running? What charset is your file (and therefore the subject you're matching) in?

Comment: it is then likely possible that other factors are affecting it, this is actually a string coming from a crawler, I will try to fix this. thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('#\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?#', '£2.35', $match);
var_dump($match);
```

gives

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "2.35"
}
```

even on PHP 5.2 : http://codepad.viper-7.com/9nFhET

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll find the value at the index 1 of the array ( `$matches[1]` )

Try something like that :

```
<?php
preg_match('/[0-9]+\.([0-9]+)/', '£3.25', $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

That gives :

```
Array
(
    [0] => £3.25
    [1] => 25
)
```

Comment: why would you expect the match at index 1 ? Aren't full matches stored in the first array, so that if you have 2 matches the fist one will be at index 0 and the last at index 1 in this array ? mk_89 used non capturing group in the example

Answer (score 0):

I can repro an issue with decimals on this tester site:
http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm

If you replace the escaped dot with a character class that contains a dot it works:

```
[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]*)?
```

Btw: is it possible that you get the dot but no digits after it ? 
If not I would replace the `[0-9]*` with either `[0-9]+` or a specific number of digits expected `[0-9]{2}`