# preg_match only nummber, spaces and currency format allowed

Tags: php, preg-match

In my php i use preg_match to validate input texts. The textbox used for currency value like 5000, or 5000.00 or can accept blank.

```
 $pattrn="/^[0-9]{10}$/";
```

By using this it can validate number only.
How to filter this input using preg_match ?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371476/preg-match-decimals-not-working

Comment: Try `$pattrn = "/^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$/";`.

Comment: Hey there stranger @AmalMurali ;-)

Comment: @Amal Murali: what about the blank?

Comment: See the edited comment, @machineaddict.

Comment: Can accept; 6000.00, 6000 and empty

Comment: @BikashMahata: The regex I've posted matches all those

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$pattrn = "/^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$/";
```

Explanation:

```
/^             # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(?:            # Begin a non-capturing group
    \d+        #   Match one or more digits from 0-9
    (?:        #   Begin a non-capturing group
        \.\d+  #    Match a dot (.) followed by one more digits from 0-9
    )?         #   Make the capturing group optional
)?             # Make the capturing group optional
$/             # Assert positon at the end of the string
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qP2bN9/1)

Answer (score 0):

you should use  $pattrn="^((?:\d.\d{3}.|\d{1,3}.)?\d{1,3},\d{1,2})$";

see sample here [preg_match() or similar function for checking currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850022/preg-match-or-similar-function-for-checking-currency)